# isotope (again!) overlaping images Vertical

Tags: vertical-alignment, jquery-isotope, overlapping

i've searched, i've tried but i couldn't find the answer.
I've got many images in isotope filtering, i've got imagesLoaded but images are still overlaping at each other in vertical.
Here's the link http://cpmedia.pl/test/portfolio.html

the code:

```
$(function(){
var $container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.itemwrap',
        layoutMode: 'horizontal',
        horizontal: {
            verticalAlignment: 0.5
        }
    });
});
```

});

and stil nothing...

Comment: According to isotope v1 docs, horizontal layout mode is not included in isotope.pkgd.js and must be installed separately. I do not see it installed on your site.

Comment: but the problem is not with the horizontal layout but with vertical ...

Comment: I'm not talking about your layout problem but what you have selected as your layoutMode. It is a problem since the layoutMode you are selecting is "horizontal". So how does that layourMode actually work if it is not included in your js?

Comment: ok, so in that case i don't know what should i do, site at hdd works good, at serwer don't... please give me info :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you are loading jquery twice, once by itself and again with yepnope. Second, you are calling isotope twice as well, once with imagesloaded on #container ( which I don't see on your page) and again on . portfolioContainer, which does exist but is not called using imagesLoaded. You need to load jQuery once, and call isotope once and try this code:

```
 $(function(){
 var $container = $('.portfolioContainer');
 $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.itemwrap',
    layoutMode: 'horizontal',
    horizontal: {
        verticalAlignment: 0.5
    }
});
});
});
```

If you want to use horizontal, then get it [here](https://raw.github.com/metafizzy/isotope-horizontal/master/horizontal.js) and load it as well

**ADDENDUM:**

Looking at your source, you are still loading multiple copies of your js files. This is what I see in your source:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/core/libs/js/loader.js"></script>
<script src="assets/core/libs/js/vendor/jquery.livetwitter.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/core/libs/js/vendor/jquery.selestnav.min.js"></script><script src="assets/core/libs/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="assets/core/libs/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="assets/user/user.js"></script><script src="skinme/skinme.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>  <script src="./assets/core/libs/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/core/libs/js/loader.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/html5lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/core/libs/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/core/libs/js/jquery.livetwitter.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/core/libs/js/jquery.jribbble.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/core/libs/js/jquery.selestnav.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/core/libs/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/core/libs/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/core/libs/js/user.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/core/libs/js/skinme.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/core/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
```

Comment: See my addendum. You need to fix  yepnope first I think. And I still see isotope loaded multiple times.

Comment: i don't see so many js in my codee...
also there is yepnope in loader.js

Comment: It's your generated source.

Comment: then how come when you open view-source:http://cpmedia.pl/test/portfolio.html and shearch for example for loader.js it's only once in 48th line? Same with other js

Comment: Google generated source for an explanation.

Comment: i don't understand. there's no so many js even duplicated js in the code, no matter if i view it through the google view or through notepad or anything else...

Comment: You need to search Google for the term "generated source" so you know what it is. When someone says Google this, they don't mean open it in google view, it means search for it. I will sign off at this point and hope that someone can help you with your problems. Hint = fix your yepnope